# A set being open in the product of two topologies $X$ and $Y$

Tags: general-topology

Show that in a product of two topologies $X$ and $Y$, $X \times Y$ a subset $T \subset X \times Y$ iff it can be expressed as the product of unions of open sets of $X$ and $Y$.

My attempt:

Now let's write $T$ as $A \times B$ to be more clear. As a subspace of $X \times Y$,the product topology on $A \times B$ is the same as the topology $A \times B$ inherits as a subspace of $X \times Y$.

Couldn't move any further? Should I somehow prove in what conditions $A \times B$ becomes a topology? (So that they become open?). And also I can't really move further because I'm not given the topology of $X \times Y$. I don't know how open sets look like in $X \times Y$.

Comment: The topology on $X\times Y$ is _likely_ the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).  There are categorical reasons for why this is the "best" choice of a topology on $X\times Y$, and for this reason when people talk about a "product of two topologies", they generally mean that.

Comment: The sentence you wrote is incorrect. It should be: "iff it can be expressed as the union of the products of open sets if $X$ and $Y$." The "union" comes before "the product."

Comment: "Now let's write $T$ as $A\times B$...." That isn't necessarily possible.

Comment: For example, if $X=Y=\mathbb R$ with the usual topologies, then $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<1\}$ is open in $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$, but it is not of the form $A\times B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the collection $\mathcal{B}=\{U_1 \times U_2 \subseteq X \times Y: U_1 \text{ open in } X, U_2 \text{ open in } Y\}$ is a *base* for a topology on $X \times Y$, the so-called product topology (it's not a topology as $\mathcal{B}$ is not closed under unions, but it *is* closed under intersections, and covers $X \times Y$; the latter 2 imply it's a base for some topology).

The topology $\mathcal{B}$ is a base of is exactly the set of all unions of members of $\mathcal{B}$. This is just standard general theory. So there is nothing to prove, really.

The subspace topology is irrelevant to your question.